# Drarry Harry Potter fan fiction where Draco has to be Harry’s familiar

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

Draco has to pretend to be Harry’s familiar so he doesn’t get caught by Voldemort. I think it was Snape that got him to do it. He’s an Animagus which is a silver fox and no one else knows that it’s actually Draco but eventually Hermione, Ron and Ginny find out when they see Draco and Harry together and Draco has the foxes collar on.

Answer (score 3):

## [*Familiar*](https://archiveofourown.org/works/16202171) (2018) by [larrysmeanttobe](https://archiveofourown.org/users/larrysmeanttobe/pseuds/larrysmeanttobe)

***"Draco has to pretend to be Harry’s familiar so he doesn’t get caught by Voldemort. I think it was Snape that got him to do it."***

> "You'll stay a fox Draco, Potter will take you to McGonagall and say that he found you and you two bonded. You will pretend to have Draco as your familiar while I handle everything else, do not tell a soul who he is and that he's actually an animagus. Now I do not need either of you sobbing about how much you hate one another because both of you will be dead in no time unless you do as said."

***"He’s an Animagus which is a silver fox and no one else knows that it’s actually Draco"***

> If anyone would ask Harry he'd say that he was actually intelligent enough to agree and do what was the best for him but in reality he did not move because he wasn't able to. He wanted to do many things when Death Eaters appeared but he felt stunned, frozen to the spot after watching Draco lose his form and shrunk down, leaving a beautiful fox behind. The fox.
>
> That's when Harry understood why the, he-thought-to-be-familiar, was so mean to him, it was Draco all along. His jaw was probably permanently lost, quite amazed that he was able to perform such complicated magic. He was an animagus.

***"eventually Hermione, Ron and Ginny find out when they see Draco and Harry together and Draco has the foxes collar on."***

> "Ron, I think Dragon was Malfoy. He must be an animagus, that's literally the only way this makes sense. I'm so dumb, I should have known from the first second when Harry was rude to his familiar, a bonded wizard would not do that. It just...it doesn't make any sense, that must be why I never figured it out. Harry and Malfoy make no sense."

Comment: It’s not that one but thanks for trying

Answer (score 1):

I found it!! I knew I remembered what you were looking for. So the story starts off during the summer with draco as a ferret and Harry rescues him, and to help him stay under cover when they return to school draco pretends to be Harry’s pet fox.

Ferret in My Shoe by MikoGoddess
It’s on fanfiction.net

Summary:

Harry finds Malfoy in a petshop and brings him home, wanting to know why he was there, and why he was a ferret again. What ensues is a bit of this, a bit of that, and a dash of slash. HPDM, after 6th year, no DH. Now with more plot!
Harry Potter, T, English, Romance, chapters: 13, words: 112k+, favs: 1k+, follows: 571, updated: Mar 20, 2008 published: Nov 11, 2007, Draco M., Harry P.

Expert from chapter 6
“  They received many stares, and people whispered as they passed, wondering why Harry Potter had a silver fox following him around now, and where he had gotten it. He ignored most, and smiled at some when he knew them, but mostly he just walked quickly past everybody and onto the train. When he finally did find one of the further-most compartments, Harry put his suitcases onto the rack, and flopped down in one of the window seats. Draco hopped up onto the seat next to him, and laid his head across Harry's lap.

Harry looked down in surprise, and smiled as the fox appeared to be drifting off to sleep. "Tired, Draco?"

A slight huff was his only response, and Harry chuckled. "I told you not to stay up too late." Draco opened one eye and glared. ”

Hope this helped.